# Environment variables don't work in PyCharm for using in Tweepy

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables

I can't retrieve environment variables.

I tried a sample code snippet from the `Tweepy` documentation without environment variables and it worked as it should. I defined the needed variables directly in the code.

Then I defined **4 environment variables** for `consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token and access_token_secret` but it didn't work anymore. What makes me wonder is that I can access the environment variables for example with `print(os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'])` and the output is correct.

There aren't any typos in the keys. I double checked it.

This code works:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'xyz'
consumer_secret = 'xyz'
access_token = 'xyz'
access_token_secret = 'xyz'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

This code doesn't work:

```
import os
import tweepy

consumer_key = os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY']
consumer_secret = os.environ['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
access_token = os.environ['TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN']
access_token_secret = os.environ['TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "[...]/testing.py", line 28, in <module>
   public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
File "[...]venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call 
   return method.execute()
File "[...]\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute 
   raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code) tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 32, 'message': 'Could not authenticate you.'}]
```

Comment: Are you sure every env variable is set or read correctly ? Try to print them all in your code or debug and see if all 4 variables are set...

Comment: Hi Dinko. I double checked the variables. I printed them (all 4) and they displayed absolutely right right out of the env variables. I don't understand it. If I pass them directly in the code it works, but doesn't if I use the env variables.

I started another project from scratch and testet it there. It worked. But I would like to know, what the problem is with the first project.

Comment: Can't help more. If they are read correctly as you say, it should be same as a code above. Unless they are somehow modified...

Answer (score -1):

You need to upload the dotenv library

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Comment: This library doesn't help define environment variables from jetbrain ides. I assume you are loading a `.env` file in Python? Where the question is not doing that?